# Alternatives to Laban Movement Analysis

Tags: motor, communication

[Laban Movement Analysis (LMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laban_Movement_Analysis) is an approach for describing movements using four main descriptors:

- **Body**: which body parts move
- **Space**: how much space is being taken up by the movement
- **Effort**: the dynamic qualities of the movement
- **Shape**: where the body parts are moving

It's been used for human gesture understanding in [various human-computer interaction systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laban_Movement_Analysis#Use_in_Human-Computer_Interaction). Are there other frameworks or approaches that have been shown to be as effective? I feel like Affect Control Theory should have some relation to this, but I'm not sure what it might be.