# What is inter-rater agreement for Laban Movement Analysis?

Tags: emotion, motor

Annotation of datasets, such as those used in action [1] and emotion recognition [2], using [Laban Movement Analysis](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16673/4397) (LMA) is usually done by Certified Laban Movement Analyst (CLMA). How much consensus is there between separately working Laban Movement Analysts when it comes to labeling various datasets?

---

1. "[Multitask learning for Laban movement analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281286489_Multitask_Learning_for_Laban_Movement_Analysis)" (2015)
2. "[Emotion Regulation through Movement: Unique Sets of Movement Characteristics are Associated with and Enhance Basic Emotions](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.02030/full)" (2016)